# Could not run Simple CV python code after installation

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I installed simple CV using simple cv superpack that i downloaded from simple cv website.Then i tried to run the Hello World program provided in the same website.
My system runs windows 7 32 bit and i have a web cam connected to my system that works fine.

```
the code is :


    from SimpleCV import *
    cam = Camera()
    while True:
        img = cam.getImage()
        img.show()
```

---

I get the following error when i run the above code ...

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Balaji\Downloads\helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    from SimpleCV import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.base import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\base.py", line 23, in <module>
    import scipy.stats.stats as sss  #for auto white balance
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 198, in <module>
    import distributions
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from nonlin import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\nonlin.py", line 115, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse.linalg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from csgraph import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'csgraph_to_masked'
>>>
```

---

I also tried with some other simple cv code i get the same error...

But when i tried to run an opencv code it works fine .. that open cv code is

---

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('myimge.jpg',0)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
        cv2.imwrite('myimgegray.png',img)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I found the solution...

Comment: the scipy version that comes with simplecv superpack is an old version so installing scipy once separately gets the job done..Scipy latest release will be available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.15.1/